# How can I give a dictionary value multiple keys?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

Suppose I have the following dictionary of colors:

```
COLORS = {
    "green":  "\033[32m",
    "yellow": "\033[33m",
}
```

How can I assign multiple keys to one value so a user could also type something like this too?

```
print COLORS["yellow"]
print COLORS["color-yellow"]

print COLORS["GREEN"]
print COLORS["GreenColor"]
```

Comment: I think it is natural with dict, as long as you don't care the multiple storage for the value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Populate the dictionary with color names:

```
COLORS = {
    "green":  "\033[32m",
    "yellow": "\033[33m",
}
for c in list(COLORS):
    color = COLORS[c]
    COLORS['color-' + c] = color
    COLORS[c.upper()] = color
    COLORS[c.capitalize() + 'Color'] = color
```

**NOTE**: use of `list(..)` to get a copy of keys: to prevent `RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration`.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it helps, but if you know the keys then you can use like that below:-

```
my_dict = dict.fromKeys(["yellow","color-yellow"],"\033[33m")
my_dict.update(my_dict.fromkeys(["GREEN","GreenColor"],"\033[32m"))
COLORS.update(my_dict)
```

**Output:-**

> {'green': '\x1b[32m', 'color-yellow': '\x1b[33m', 'GREEN': '\x1b[32m',
>   'GreenColor': '\x1b[32m', 'yellow': '\x1b[33m'}